# How to customize Spring Security UI adding fields for Grails 3.2.9 and Spring Security UI 3.0.0.M2

Tags: spring, security, user-interface, grails-plugin, grails3

I have installed Spring Security UI. It is working with the default fields:

- username
- email
- password
- password2

I want to add more fields. For example:

- phoneNumber
- firstName
- lastName

So I type:

grails s2ui-override register packageName
It creates an empty class which extends: grails.plugins.springsecurity.ui.RegisterController.

I've seen the previous questions but their solutions do not apply for Grails 3.2.9 (or Grails 3.2) and Spring Security UI 3.0.0.M2.

Does anyone know how to do this easily for the newer Grails version.

Comment: Hello, did you find any answer to this by any chance? trying to accomplish the same thing on a legacy system and the docs have not been helpful...

Answer (score -1):

Add the below to RegisterCommand :

```
String organisation

String landline

String mobile

static constraints = { ...

organisation blank: false

mobile blank: false

}
```

Add the below to `User.groovy` domain :

```
String organisation

String landline

String mobile

static constraints = {

...

mobile nullable:false

organisation nullable:false

}
```

add this to `index.gsp` :

```
<s2ui:textFieldRow name='organisation' bean="${command}" value="${command.organisation}"

                           size='40'  class='form-control' labelCodeDefault='Organisation' labelCode='user.organisation.label'/>



<s2ui:textFieldRow name='mobile' bean="${command}" value="${command.mobile}"

                           size='40'  class='form-control' labelCodeDefault='Mobile' labelCode='user.mobile.label'/>



<s2ui:textFieldRow name='landline' bean="${command}" value="${command.landline}"

                           size='40'  class='form-control' labelCodeDefault='Landline' labelCode='user.landline.label'>
```

reference [link](http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Add-fields-in-Register-page-of-Spring-Security-UI)

Comment: I don't think this is correct, as you will get a no method signature found error for the createUser method in the springSecurityUiService